# WebService returning JSONP response

Tags: web-services, sencha-touch, jsonp

Where can i find a web service which returns a JSONP response as is hosted in the internet?

Answer (score 1):

WordPress with the JSON plugin can provide that functionality.. Oh and I believe twitter has a JSON api that will return JSONP.